# Acceso a objeto público estático con indices de array devuelve Warning: Illegal string offset - PHP

Tags: php, array, object

**Punto 1: Declaración del objeto y uso básico**

Tengo una *clase padre* donde llamo y manejo otras *sub-clases*. Esta tiene por nombre `CORE`, en donde declaro un objeto público y estático para guardar futuros valores.

Porque lo siguiente...

```
class CORE{
    public static $ObjClassInst; # Objeto donde se guarda la instancia de las clases Hijas
    public static $ObjSiS; #Ejemplo de la declaración del Objeto
    public function __construct() {
        self::$ObjClassInst['Generic']['APPMANAGER']->RunInit();
    }
}
```

... me permite acceder a él desde cualquier función de la misma clase mediante la citación:

```
self::$ObjSiS = 'Hola Mundo'; # Esto es un ejemplo
```

... me permite acceder a él desde cualquier *clase hija* mediante la citación:

```
CORE::$ObjSiS = 'Hola Mundo'; # Esto es un ejemplo
```

**Punto 2: Manipulación del *objeto* y poblar con los datos por defecto**

Tengo una clase para el manejo de variables, donde tomo el objeto y le asigno índices de array y valores por defecto.

Esto ocurre sin ningún problema:

```
class Class_VarsManager {
    public function DecVars() {
        #Directorio de Variables a Utilizar por el Sistema
        #Sistema
        CORE::$ObjSiS['SIS']['MEMORYUSAGE']['STANDBY']= NULL; #Guardara la memoria numerica usada por el sistema al inicio de cada ejecucion.
        CORE::$ObjSiS['SIS']['MEMORYUSAGE']['STANDBYTXT'] = NULL; #Guardara la memoria Textual usada por el sistema al inicio de cada ejecucion.
        CORE::$ObjSiS['SIS']['MEMORYUSAGE']['LASTRUN']= NULL; #Guarda la memoria Numerica de la ultima ejecucion
        CORE::$ObjSiS['SIS']['MEMORYUSAGE']['RUNNING']= NULL; #Guardara la memoria Numerica usada por el sistema al final de cada ejecucion.
        CORE::$ObjSiS['SIS']['MEMORYUSAGE']['RUNNINGTXT'] = NULL; #Guardara la memoria Textual usada por el sistema al final de cada ejecucion.
        CORE::$ObjSiS['SIS']['HTTPR']['HTTPM']= NULL; #Guardara el Metodo en el que se esta recibiendo una peticion HTTP_REQUEST si existe GET O POST
        CORE::$ObjSiS['SIS']['HTTPR']['HTTPST']   = false; #Guardara si se Recibio alguna peticion HTTP_REQUEST false predeterminado, true
        CORE::$ObjSiS['SIS']['HTTPR']['PROTOCOL'] = NULL; #Guardara el Metodo en el que se esta recibiendo una peticion HTTP_REQUEST si existe segun verificacion
        CORE::$ObjSiS['SIS']['HTTPR']['CHECK']= NULL; #Guardara el Metodo en el que se esta recibiendo una peticion HTTP_REQUEST si existe segun verificacion
        #DISPLAY
        CORE::$ObjSiS['DISPLAY']['DIC']['DEFULT']= DEFAULTLANG; #Indica el Idioma que cargara la aplicacion por Defecto.
        CORE::$ObjSiS['DISPLAY']['DIC']['DEVICE']= NULL; #Indica el Idioma que cargara la aplicacion Para el Dispositivo.
        CORE::$ObjSiS['DISPLAY']['DIC']['USERSES']   = NULL; #Indica el Idioma que cargara la aplicacion Para el Usuario segun la Sesion.
        CORE::$ObjSiS['DISPLAY']['DIC']['USERDB']= NULL; #Indica el Idioma que cargara la aplicacion Para el Usuario segun la base de Datos.
        CORE::$ObjSiS['DISPLAY']['DIC']['LANG']  = NULL; #Indica el Idioma que cargara la aplicacion Para el Usuario.
        CORE::$ObjSiS['DISPLAY']['DIC']['FILE']  = NULL; #Indicamos por Fecto que el Archivo no Existe.
        CORE::$ObjSiS['DISPLAY']['DIC']['FILE']['Exist'] = false; #Indicamos por Fecto que el Archivo no Existe.
        CORE::$ObjSiS['DISPLAY']['DIC']['FILE']['ARRAY'] = NULL; #Indicamos por Fecto que el Archivo no Existe.
        CORE::$ObjSiS['DISPLAY']['SUCCESSFUL']   = NULL; #Establecemos la variable que almacenara si una ejecucion fue correcta por pantalla
        CORE::$ObjSiS['DISPLAY']['SUCCESSFUL']['MODAL1'] = NULL; #Establecemos la variable que almacenara si una ejecucion fue correcta por Modal 1
        CORE::$ObjSiS['DISPLAY']['SUCCESSFUL']['MODAL2'] = NULL; #Establecemos la variable que almacenara si una ejecucion fue correcta por Modal 2
        CORE::$ObjSiS['DISPLAY']['ERROR']= NULL; #Establecemos la Variable que Almacenara si una ejecucion termino en error por pantalla
        CORE::$ObjSiS['DISPLAY']['ERROR']['MODAL1']  = NULL; #Establecemos la Variable que Almacenara si una ejecucion termino en error por Modal 1
        CORE::$ObjSiS['DISPLAY']['ERROR']['MODAL2']  = NULL; #Establecemos la Variable que Almacenara si una ejecucion termino en error por Modal 2
        CORE::$ObjSiS['DISPLAY']['ALERT']= NULL; #Establecemos la Variable que Almacenara si una ejecucion termino con alguna alerta por pantalla
        CORE::$ObjSiS['DISPLAY']['ALERT']['MODAL1']  = NULL; #Establecemos la Variable que Almacenara si una ejecucion termino con alguna alerta por Modal 1
        CORE::$ObjSiS['DISPLAY']['ALERT']['MODAL2']  = NULL; #Establecemos la Variable que Almacenara si una ejecucion termino con alguna alerta por Modal 2
        CORE::$ObjSiS['DISPLAY']['DEBUG']= NULL; #Establecemos la Salida de Error DEBUG por pantalla
        CORE::$ObjSiS['DISPLAY']['DEBUG']['MODAL1']  = NULL; #Establecemos la Salida de Error DEBUG por Modal 1
        CORE::$ObjSiS['DISPLAY']['DEBUG']['MODAL2']  = NULL; #Establecemos la Salida de Error DEBUG por Modal 2
        CORE::$ObjSiS['DISPLAY']['HOME'] = 1; #Home=1(WebSite), Home=2 (DashBoard Administrativo)
        CORE::$ObjSiS['DISPLAY']['TOBROWSER']= []; #Contenido HTML Fusionado para mostrar.
        CORE::$ObjSiS['DISPLAY']['HTML']['HEADER']   = ''; #Contenido HTML Head
        CORE::$ObjSiS['DISPLAY']['HTML']['JSCRIPT']  = ''; #Contenido HTML Carga de Javascript
        CORE::$ObjSiS['DISPLAY']['HTML']['BODYSTART']= ''; #Contenido HTML Carga Apertura Body
        CORE::$ObjSiS['DISPLAY']['HTML']['BODYCLOSE']= ''; #Contenido HTML Carga Cierre Body
        CORE::$ObjSiS['DISPLAY']['HTML']['VIRTUALAREA']  = ''; #Contenido HTML Carga Virtual de Modal y otros elementos.
        CORE::$ObjSiS['DISPLAY']['HTML']['OUTJSON']  = false; #Contenido HTML Fusionado para mostrar.
        CORE::$ObjSiS['TRANSLATION'] = [];

        #USER
        CORE::$ObjSiS['USER']['STLOGGED'] = false; #Inicializamos el estatus del Usuario por defecto
        #DEVICE
        CORE::$ObjSiS['DEVICE']['MOBILE'] = false; #Inicializamos el tipo de Dispositivo que ultizamos por defecto
        #VARIABLES
        CORE::$ObjSiS['VAR']['EXIST']['CHECK'] = false; #Establcemos el valor por defecto para la verificacion de si una variable existe
        #Cronos
        CORE::$ObjSiS['CRON']['IS']['RUN'] = NULL; #Establecemos el Valor por defecto para controlar si un Proceso de Cron Esta en ejecucion

    }
}
```

Hasta este momento todo va bien, no me sale ninguna advertencia ni ningún tipo de error.

**Punto 3: Error de acceso al índice especifico en el objeto.**

En una sección del sistema, intento utilizar uno de los valores del array previamente declarado.

```
$encript = CORE::$ObjSiS['DISPLAY']['HTML']['OUTJSON']; #debe devolver true o false.
```

... el problema es que me sale un error tipo ilegal, les dejo los ejemplos; y resulta una advertencia de la siguiente manera:

```
Warning: Illegal string offset 'OUTJSON'
```

He verificado que no exista error de sintaxis, o error lógico, todo ocurre adecuadamente:

1. Establezco el objeto.
2. Escribo los arrays.
3. Accedo al array. (Error de indice)

Como verán, la declaración de todo el array ocurre y sus valores por defecto ocurren en una sola función.

Lo podrán ver directamente en el proyecto:

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B0qbx2QzVDgFaDBRODVMMC1aT2c

Deben tomar en cuenta que la arquitectura es orientada al objeto y no verán una declaración clásica de instancia de clases, ni verán el tradicional llamado a funciones. Para esto se utiliza el llamado por referencia de objeto de la siguiente forma:

```
class Class_AppManager {
    public function RunInit() {
        CORE::$ObjClassInst['Generic']['VARSMANAGER']->DecVars();
    }
}
```

**Nota:** Como verán `RunInit()` es la función que corro en el constructor de la función padre `CORE` para inicializar la aplicación. En el proyecto podrán ver más detalles sobre el código; Estos son solo ejemplos.

En un *debug* hice el `var_dump` del objeto, existen todos los índices necesarios y establecidos y no aparece el índice `OUTJSON`, la única manera de solucionarlo es cambiando la dimensión del array a algo mas corto `CORE::$ObjSiS['DISPLAY']['OUTJSON'];`

**Actualización:**

Veo que el array funciona correctamente incluso el índice `OUTJSON`, he de suponer que mi instalación local de *XAMPP* de alguna manera estaba cacheando este objeto o array, pero no logré darme cuenta cuál es el error real, si desean ver los detalles del proyecto pueden descargarlo del *Google Drive*.

**No es ningún error por instanciación o llamado a la función; Esta pregunta fue editada buscando dispersar alguna dudas o errores de interpretación del código o arquitectura**

Comment: Copie este codigo, seguido de una instancia de la clase y un llamado a las dos funciones en el orden en que estan declaradas y no consigo reproducir el error. Deberia agregar que no es un error reqalmente, solo un warning y que se genera porque nunca declaras explicitamente un array

Comment: Una vez comenzada, el sistema no permite incrementar la cantidad de la recompensa. Si quieres ofrecer más, debes esperar a que termine para ofrecer una nueva recompensa.

Comment: Sugiero cambiar en enlace de Google Drive y subirlo a algún lugar público o de lo contrario eliminar el enlace, ya que pide permiso, no todo el mundo puede verlo.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Te faltan algunas cosas:

1. Para poder usar valores como `CORE::$ObjSiS`, ese miembro debe ser declarado como `static` en la clase. No lo tienes así. **Nota:** Este error inicial fue corregido [en una posterior edición del código](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/142166/revisions) mostrado en la pregunta. No obstante dejo aquí el dato, dada la dificultad particular de este caso.
2. Al menos según el código que muestras en tu pregunta, los valores correspondientes a `$ObjSiS` **son asignados dentro del método `ShowContent()` de la clase `Class_VarsManager`**. Entonces, dado que esa clase **no es estática**, debes crear una instancia de ella y luego invocar al método que llena a `$ObjSiS`.

Yo he reproducido exactamente el código que has presentado en tu pregunta, como podrás verificar en el demo más abajo, si creo una instancia de la clase `Class_VarsManager` y luego invoco al método `DecVars()`, que es el que, según la lógica presentada en tu pregunta, **asigna valores a `$ObjSiS`**, podrás comprobar que, en efecto, obtienes lo que quieres obtener, **según este comentario en tu propio código: `#debe devolver true o false.`**

**NOTA:** Aquí no estamos en ningún caso cambiando nada en cuanto a métodos de programación. Aquí se sigue aplicando la POO. La única función que se usa fuera de una clase es `ShowContent()`, **exactamente como la usas tú mismo en el código de tu pregunta.**

Si escribes **la función que ya tienes** así:

```
function ShowContent() {
     $clsVars=new Class_VarsManager();
     $clsVars->DecVars();
     $encript = CORE::$ObjSiS['DISPLAY']['HTML']['OUTJSON']; #debe devolver true o false.
     return $encript;
}
```

Y luego la pruebas:

```
$encript=ShowContent();
var_dump($encript);
```

Tendrás este resultado:

```
bool(false)
```

---

### Código completo corregido

[VER DEMO EN REXTESTER](http://rextester.com/XGVKH78835)

```
<?php
class CORE{
    public static $ObjSiS; #Ejemplo de la declaración del Objeto
}      

 class Class_VarsManager {
    public  function DecVars() {
        #Directorio de Variables a Utilizar por el Sistema
        #Sistema
        CORE::$ObjSiS['SIS']['MEMORYUSAGE']['STANDBY']    = NULL; #Guardara la memoria numerica usada por el sistema al inicio de cada ejecucion.
        CORE::$ObjSiS['SIS']['MEMORYUSAGE']['STANDBYTXT'] = NULL; #Guardara la memoria Textual usada por el sistema al inicio de cada ejecucion.
        CORE::$ObjSiS['SIS']['MEMORYUSAGE']['LASTRUN']    = NULL; #Guarda la memoria Numerica de la ultima ejecucion
        CORE::$ObjSiS['SIS']['MEMORYUSAGE']['RUNNING']    = NULL; #Guardara la memoria Numerica usada por el sistema al final de cada ejecucion.
        CORE::$ObjSiS['SIS']['MEMORYUSAGE']['RUNNINGTXT'] = NULL; #Guardara la memoria Textual usada por el sistema al final de cada ejecucion.
        CORE::$ObjSiS['SIS']['HTTPR']['HTTPM']            = NULL; #Guardara el Metodo en el que se esta recibiendo una peticion HTTP_REQUEST si existe GET O POST
        CORE::$ObjSiS['SIS']['HTTPR']['HTTPST']           = false; #Guardara si se Recibio alguna peticion HTTP_REQUEST false predeterminado, true
        CORE::$ObjSiS['SIS']['HTTPR']['PROTOCOL']         = NULL; #Guardara el Metodo en el que se esta recibiendo una peticion HTTP_REQUEST si existe segun verificacion
        CORE::$ObjSiS['SIS']['HTTPR']['CHECK']            = NULL; #Guardara el Metodo en el que se esta recibiendo una peticion HTTP_REQUEST si existe segun verificacion
        #DISPLAY
        //CORE::$ObjSiS['DISPLAY']['DIC']['DEFULT']        = DEFAULTLANG; #Indica el Idioma que cargara la aplicacion por Defecto.
        CORE::$ObjSiS['DISPLAY']['DIC']['DEVICE']        = NULL; #Indica el Idioma que cargara la aplicacion Para el Dispositivo.
        CORE::$ObjSiS['DISPLAY']['DIC']['USERSES']       = NULL; #Indica el Idioma que cargara la aplicacion Para el Usuario segun la Sesion.
        CORE::$ObjSiS['DISPLAY']['DIC']['USERDB']        = NULL; #Indica el Idioma que cargara la aplicacion Para el Usuario segun la base de Datos.
        CORE::$ObjSiS['DISPLAY']['DIC']['LANG']          = NULL; #Indica el Idioma que cargara la aplicacion Para el Usuario.
        CORE::$ObjSiS['DISPLAY']['DIC']['FILE']          = NULL; #Indicamos por Fecto que el Archivo no Existe.
        CORE::$ObjSiS['DISPLAY']['DIC']['FILE']['Exist'] = false; #Indicamos por Fecto que el Archivo no Existe.
        CORE::$ObjSiS['DISPLAY']['DIC']['FILE']['ARRAY'] = NULL; #Indicamos por Fecto que el Archivo no Existe.
        CORE::$ObjSiS['DISPLAY']['SUCCESSFUL']           = NULL; #Establecemos la variable que almacenara si una ejecucion fue correcta por pantalla
        CORE::$ObjSiS['DISPLAY']['SUCCESSFUL']['MODAL1'] = NULL; #Establecemos la variable que almacenara si una ejecucion fue correcta por Modal 1
        CORE::$ObjSiS['DISPLAY']['SUCCESSFUL']['MODAL2'] = NULL; #Establecemos la variable que almacenara si una ejecucion fue correcta por Modal 2
        CORE::$ObjSiS['DISPLAY']['ERROR']                = NULL; #Establecemos la Variable que Almacenara si una ejecucion termino en error por pantalla
        CORE::$ObjSiS['DISPLAY']['ERROR']['MODAL1']      = NULL; #Establecemos la Variable que Almacenara si una ejecucion termino en error por Modal 1
        CORE::$ObjSiS['DISPLAY']['ERROR']['MODAL2']      = NULL; #Establecemos la Variable que Almacenara si una ejecucion termino en error por Modal 2
        CORE::$ObjSiS['DISPLAY']['ALERT']                = NULL; #Establecemos la Variable que Almacenara si una ejecucion termino con alguna alerta por pantalla
        CORE::$ObjSiS['DISPLAY']['ALERT']['MODAL1']      = NULL; #Establecemos la Variable que Almacenara si una ejecucion termino con alguna alerta por Modal 1
        CORE::$ObjSiS['DISPLAY']['ALERT']['MODAL2']      = NULL; #Establecemos la Variable que Almacenara si una ejecucion termino con alguna alerta por Modal 2
        CORE::$ObjSiS['DISPLAY']['DEBUG']                = NULL; #Establecemos la Salida de Error DEBUG por pantalla
        CORE::$ObjSiS['DISPLAY']['DEBUG']['MODAL1']      = NULL; #Establecemos la Salida de Error DEBUG por Modal 1
        CORE::$ObjSiS['DISPLAY']['DEBUG']['MODAL2']      = NULL; #Establecemos la Salida de Error DEBUG por Modal 2
        CORE::$ObjSiS['DISPLAY']['HOME']                 = 1; #Home=1(WebSite), Home=2 (DashBoard Administrativo)
        CORE::$ObjSiS['DISPLAY']['TOBROWSER']            = []; #Contenido HTML Fusionado para mostrar.
        CORE::$ObjSiS['DISPLAY']['HTML']['HEADER']       = ''; #Contenido HTML Head
        CORE::$ObjSiS['DISPLAY']['HTML']['JSCRIPT']      = ''; #Contenido HTML Carga de Javascript
        CORE::$ObjSiS['DISPLAY']['HTML']['BODYSTART']    = ''; #Contenido HTML Carga Apertura Body
        CORE::$ObjSiS['DISPLAY']['HTML']['BODYCLOSE']    = ''; #Contenido HTML Carga Cierre Body
        CORE::$ObjSiS['DISPLAY']['HTML']['VIRTUALAREA']  = ''; #Contenido HTML Carga Virtual de Modal y otros elementos.
        CORE::$ObjSiS['DISPLAY']['HTML']['OUTJSON']      = false; #Contenido HTML Fusionado para mostrar.
        CORE::$ObjSiS['TRANSLATION']                     = [];


    }
}

    $encript=ShowContent();
    var_dump($encript);


function ShowContent() {
     $clsVars=new Class_VarsManager();
     $clsVars->DecVars();
     $encript = CORE::$ObjSiS['DISPLAY']['HTML']['OUTJSON']; #debe devolver true o false.
    return $encript;
}


?>
```

Comment: no es necesario hacer la instancia de `Class_VarsManager` por que estoy llamando al objeto que es publico de la siguiente manera: `CORE::$ObjSiS['DISPLAY']['HTML']['OUTJSON'];` tampoco tengo que llamar a la funcion:   `$clsVars->DecVars(); ` ya que esta se ejecuto en otra funcion. la arquitectura que se esta empleado es Orientada a objeto no procedural como asumes.

Comment: Estás confundido. Tú llenas el objeto dentro de una función de una clase **que no es es estática `Class_VarsManager`**. Por eso te da `NULL`, porque no invocas esa función nunca. Y tienes más errores. Ahora edito y te muestro una prueba en Rextester.

Comment: no asumas cosas que no son, el objeto se declara en una clase padre; el cual es accesible en toda la APP; en una clase hija que siempre se ejecuta en el constructor, se llama a la clase `Class_VarsManager` al realizar esta ejecución en el constructor; automáticamente queda establecida la estructura del array; en el recorrido de la aplicación yo utilizo el objeto y utilizo sus valores y los actualizo; cuando llego al punto que necesito acceder a este indice en especifico me da el error, esto no ocurre con los otros indices. como te decía, no estoy usando la arquitectura que citas.

Comment: es mas agregas esta linea `$clsVars->DecVars();` y no le das un uso; y si el objeto es `static`

Comment: Ahí te puse una prueba de lo que digo, Francisco. Con esa línea `$clsVars->DecVars();` precisamente, se asignan valores a `$ObjSiS`. En rextester puedes probar, comentar, quitar esa llamada y en seguida verás que el código falla. Y sé más agradecido, que se responde con intención de ayudarte.

Comment: revisa mis comentarios ... no estas leyendo y estas asumiendo cosas.

Comment: [Editaste el código de la pregunta silenciosamente](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/142166/revisions), corrigiendo el **error** que te indico en mi **punto 1** de esta respuesta. Ahora dime, **¿cómo vas a llenar los valores de `$ObjSiS` para que no te devuelva `NULL`?** ( **punto 2** de mi respuesta). Y luego hablamos @FranciscoNúñez

Comment: no edite nada silenciosamente; te avise que el $ObjSiS si es estatico en otro comentario...

Comment: aqui el problema no es llenar el valor, tampoco he dicho que devuelva NULL, el problema es que no tiene acceso a ese indice y a los otros Si...

Comment: Perfecto @FranciscoNúñez te he mostrado un código que funciona. Si lo implementas así también te funcionará. O traslada el contenido de tu objeto `$ObjSiS` a su clase. Lo que has mostrado en la pregunta es que el objeto se llena en otra clase y nunca invocas al método que da valores al objeto. Doy este asunto por cerrado. Saludos.

Comment: yo no deseo implementar tu código necesito implementar el mio. pero como no lees los comentarios...

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73837/discussion-between-francisco-nunez-and-a-cedano).

Comment: Muy bien @FranciscoNúñez, entonces implementa tu código. Por último tendría que decirte nuevamente que tu actitud es penosa, desagradable y no conforme al espíritu de SO, pero ¡qué le vamos a hacer! **Asunto cerrado, por mi parte.**

Comment: imponer una respuesta como unica de tu parte tambien lo es... como te digo no puedo implementar tu estructura en la mia... tu estas haciendolo procedural y yo lo tengo orientado a objetos.

Comment: **esto es falso:** lo que dices que ocurre es una supocicion en el punto **2: son asignados dentro del método ** `ShowContent()` los valores del `$ObjSiS` son asignados en `RunInit()` (la responsabilidad de esta funcion es inicializar todos los datos incluso las variables que se usaran y los objetos), que hace la llamada a `DecVars();` en el proyecto. y la pregunta fue editada para dispersar esas suposiciones de interpretación donde piensan que el error esta en una funciona llamada ShowContent()

Answer (score 3):

Es porque `HTML` no este definido tampoco como un `Array`,

```
CORE::$ObjSiS['DISPLAY']['HTML'] = [];
```

Comment: no puedo guardar directamente??

Comment: no debería de ser un problema, por que me deja guardar los otros indices, sin error.??

Comment: Puedes acceder a los otros indices?

Comment: sioesi a cualquiera que intente acceder será `NULL` porque él llena el objeto en este método `DecVars()`. Lo puedes probar en el rextester de mi respuesta.

Comment: @A.Cedano lo que me parece raro es que si cambia la estructura si le funciona, por eso pense definitivamente en la manera de declarar sus arreglos y objetos

Comment: @A.Cedano trata de concentrarte en tu respuesta. y los comentarios que te hice, si puedo acceder a todos los indices; y todos tiene contenido actualizado según el proceso ..

Comment: La lógica del código posteado en la pregunta (la cual es cuestionable), es que los valores del elemento `$ObjSiS` (declarado `static` a posteriori) deben ser llenados invocando **otro método de otra clase no estática**. Ese es el código que se ha compartido y en base a eso se ha respondido. No veo de qué otra manera se pueda dar valores al objeto... Esta no es la 1ª vez que te indico un error y no lo asumes @FranciscoNúñez y esta será la última pregunta tuya que respondo. Saludos.

Comment: el problema no es dar valores al objeto como te eh explicado, puedo acceder a los otros indices y ver los valores; únicamente este indice es el que da el problema. y si observas todos los indices fueron declarados en una misma funcion... por que el ultimo indice que declare en este caso `CORE::$ObjSiS['DISPLAY']['HTML']['OUTJSON']` no es Guardado por el PHP.

Answer (score 1):

Segun tu publicación el problema no se presenta a lo largo de tu código sino cuando extraes los datos.
Con lo que muestras es **IMPOSIBLE** replicar el error sin mas información.
Debes estar re-escribiendo el objeto **$ObjSiS** durante tu código de forma que eliminas o sobre-escribes el valor que buscas.

Con una prueba simple de tu codigo

```
function ShowContent() {
        $encript = CORE::$ObjSiS['DISPLAY']['HTML']['OUTJSON']; #debe devolver true o false.
        return $encript;
}
$CVM = new Class_VarsManager();
$CVM->DecVars();

echo json_encode(ShowContent());
```

Retorna el valor que le asigne a DISPLAY->HTML->OUTJSON

Si pudieras mostrar como trabajas con la función **ShowContent**.

> En tu código tienes **ShowContent** dentro de una clase por lo cual se encuentra dentro de una clase, por falta de información de como manipulas el objeto lo muestro de la manera más simple.

Comment: hola gracias por la respuesta; he estado pensando actualizar el código y agregar un link directo al projecto ya que como código es bastante lo que existe. https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B0qbx2QzVDgFaDBRODVMMC1aT2c

Comment: si lo abres con sublimetext podras ver la ruta de cada funcion. el día de hoy intente abrir nuevamente el proyecto en local; y ya no me sale el error que indique en la pregunta, es como si el problema tenga que ver con el cache de php...